# How to get public int 'currentSlot' from grandchildren

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

im beginner and still learning please don't hate.
So my script is located in Canvas, (Canvas -> inv -> invslot) but I need to get currentSlot int from a script in invslot gameobj., how would I do that the right way? I've tried this so far but doesn't seem to work at all.

```
    void UpdateUI () {
    for (int i = 0; i < slots.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i < inventory.items.Count) {
            currentSlot = GetComponentsInChildren<InventoryScroll>();
            slots[i] = currentSlot;
            currentSlot.AddItem(inventory.items[i]); 
            Debug.Log ("Updating UI");
        } else
        {
            slots[i].ClearSlot();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT!

Here is the top of my InventoryUI, where I want to bring the int currentSlot

```
public Transform itemsParent;

Inventory inventory;

InventorySlot[] slots;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    inventory = Inventory.instance;
    inventory.onItemChangedCallback += UpdateUI;

    slots = itemsParent.GetComponentsInChildren<InventorySlot>();

}
```

But the Inventoryscroll goes this way

```
  List<GameObject> slots = new List<GameObject>();
public int currentSlot=0;
int slotsToScroll=3;
void Start() {
    foreach(Transform child in this.transform) {
        slots.Add(child.gameObject);
    }
}

void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha1)) {
        currentSlot=0;
        UpdateDisplay();
    }

    if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") >0){
        if (currentSlot<slotsToScroll) {
            currentSlot++;
        } else {
            currentSlot=0;
        }
        UpdateDisplay();
    }
 }

void UpdateDisplay() {
    for (int i = 0; i < slots.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i==currentSlot) {
            slots[i].transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.SetActive(true);
        } else {
            slots[i].transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Inventory script

```
    #region Singleton
public static Inventory instance;

void Awake () {
    if (instance != null) {
        Debug.LogWarning("More than one instance of inventory found!");
        return;
    }
    instance = this;
}

#endregion

public delegate void OnItemChanged();
```

public OnItemChanged onItemChangedCallback;

public int space = 6;

public List items = new List();

```
public bool Add (Item item) {

if (!item.isDefaultItem) {
    if(items.Count >= space) {
        Debug.Log("Not enough inventory space.");
        return false;
    }
        items.Add(item);

        if (onItemChangedCallback != null)
        onItemChangedCallback.Invoke();
}

return true;

public void Remove (Item item) {

items.Remove(item);

 if (onItemChangedCallback != null)
 onItemChangedCallback.Invoke();
```

Comment: What does `doesn't seem to work` mean exactly? Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: could you add the code for `InventoryScroll` to your question please?

Comment: I need to see all included classes .. e.g. what is `Inventory` and what fields does it have?

Answer (score 1):

Careful, Unity has two methods:

- [`GetComponentsInChildren`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentsInChildren.html)

  > Returns **all** components of Type `type` in the `GameObject` or any of its children.

  this returns a `InventoryScroll []`!
- and [`GetComponentInChildren`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentInChildren.html)

  > Returns the component of Type `type` in the `GameObject` or any of its children using depth **first** search.

  This returns one single `InventoryScroll` reference, the first one found!

Note the **`s`**!

From your description and how you use it in your code it seems like you wanted to use the latter but have an `s` too much.

The second mistake: From the variable name it sounds like you rather wanted to get an `InventorySlot` **not** an `InventoryScroll`!

So you should use

```
currentSlot = GetComponentInChildren<InventorySlot>();
```

Though it is hard to tell what your actual goal is with this code without seeing the types of `slots` and `currentSlot`.

It also appears really strange to me that you already get all `slots` in `Start` but here you overwrite

```
slots[i] = currentSlot;
```

for each `i` that is `i < inventory.items.Coun`. Also you iterate through `slots.Length` but you pass in `inventory.izems[i]` .. I don't understand what is supposed to happen here exactly.

Comment: I edited the post, and brought there a little bit of code to be more exact what I mean

Comment: See my update! Is it possible you also confused the types `InventoryScroll` and `InventorySlot` there?

Comment: The Inventory script is a script I made for scrolling through the inventory. inventoryslots  has script that only adds item and clears slot, and when scrollnig it just activates one gameobject and after scrolling out it deactivates it

Comment: So the main thing why is to add a method so the pickupable item gets into the selected slot, example u have 4 slots and ur active slot is 2, so while picking up item, the item would go into the active slot ( this time 2) and not always to fiull the slots from elft to right